# Zend preDispatch function not called in Plugin Controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have the first `Bootstrap.php` who call a plugin controller, who (the plugin) call another `Bootstrap`. And in this second `Bootstrap`, I call another plugin controller, but the `preDispatch()` function is not called ...

This the path:
`Bootstrap => Plugin (preDispatch) => Bootstrap (another) => Plugin (preDispatch not called)`

I guess, it's because the `preDispatch` is always call in the first Plugin Controller.

So, my solution is to load all my plugins in the first Bootstrap, but I don't love it ...
Do you have other idea?

EDIT: someone?

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem with this setup is, that when you register the plugins form the second bootstrap file, the `Zend_Controller_Front` has already called this method on all the registered plugins, and anything registered after this event will never receive this event call.

To get a better grasp on this concept, try looking at lines ~900-920 in `Zend_Controller_Front`. This is where the event is created, and since there can only be 1 front controller, this code will never be run twice.